# Data getting inserted in db when refresh button is pressed,

Tags: php, forms

I have a form validation code and data is getting inserted in db when refresh button is pressed. How do i stop it?
I refered to this code http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp
and then I have created db connection which the code is given below.

when the refresh button is clicked the data is getting inserted in the database. How do i stop the values getting inserted when refresh button is clicked?

Comment: include("conn.php");
$res=mysql_query("insert into validation values('$name','$email','$website','$address')");
if($res)
{
 echo "data inserted in table";
}
else
{
 echo "insertion failed";
}

Comment: as you are refresh the page the form is submitted again.

Comment: you can check for email id if it is inserted in the table echo data already added

Comment: you can use , recaptcha or such technology , so that it only work for a request, and refreshing the page will fail to pass the recaptcha.

Comment: you can use ajax to submit values. after successful insert, clear form.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the

`header('Location myfile.php');`

in the end of your if block

`if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { .... }`

After the request is done to the database,
the page will go to myfile.php.

This will not carry the POST-data with it, and if the user clicks on refresh, the data is not sent.
If you want to somehow leave a "success" message you can use:

`header('Location myfile.php?sent=success');`

Then you could listen to `$_GET['sent']` to confirm it was a success.

EDIT:

Method 2 Sessions:

First to set the sessionvariable

```
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    /* your code goes here */

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['success'] = true;
    header('Location myfile.php');
  }
```

To get the variable and reset it

```
  session_start();
  $was_success = !empty($_SESSION['success']);
  unset($_SESSION['success']);
```

Comment: in this case if he refresh the page he will get success message every time.

Comment: yes, very true but if it is a success page, then it should be there. 

In case is should only be viewed once, then session is a better option. Right before the header function. a session variable is added, to later be removed as the success message is shown.

Comment: @frahan, This works fine. however can this be done using sessions?

Comment: @frahan, its not working using session. Do u have javascript code for validation? If yes kindly share.